# How to revert radio button checked change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `.change()` placed for each radio button in table:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
        $('input[name="Options[' + i + '].Completed"]').change(function () {
            var number = $(this).attr("name").match(/\d+/g)[0];
            ...
            some action
            ...
        });
    }
```

What I'm tryin to do is to revert radio botton change in case of some condition.

By default, my radiobutten is marked as false (Yes No, No by default). If I clicked to Yes, but don't mach the condition, I need to stay on No.

I have tried to do this in this way:

```
if (... condition ...) {
     $('input[name="Options[' + i + '].Completed"]').filter('[value=False]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work (nothing happened, but condition works fine).

What am I doing wrong and how can I accomplish my goal?

**EDIT:**

radiobutton html:

```
<div id="Options_0__Completed-styler" class="jq-radio" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
    <input id="Options_0__Completed" name="Options[0].Completed" type="radio" value="True" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div class="jq-radio__div"></div>
</div>

<div id="Options_0__Completed-styler" class="jq-radio checked" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
    <input checked="checked" id="Options_0__Completed" name="Options[0].Completed" type="radio" value="False" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div class="jq-radio__div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change each radio button group to select the `false` value based on some condition? Seems a rather confusing/frustrating UI if when the user clicks `true`, nothing happens (it just stays false).

Comment: Not sure that understand you. I want to eacg radio button group have this condition. Right now if I click on Yes, condition will work, but Yes are staying checked. I want it to became No, in case if condition were true.

Comment: If the radio button is 'No' and I (as a user) clicked 'Yes' then I expect the 'Yes' button to be checked. I would be very annoyed if clicking on 'Yes' did nothing (because your code changes it immediately back to 'No'). I suggest you consider an alternative UI such as disabling the radio button based on the condition so it obvious that the value cannot be changed from 'No' to 'Yes'

Comment: My condition is actually a validator, and if it is false, then I got warning sign near the field I need to fill. So no. I don't see the problem here. Until validator becames "true", I need to revert radio button to No.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` inside `for` loop is the shared between all instances of radio buttons. You need to make copy of it for each radio button as follow:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $('input[name="Options[' + i + '].Completed"]').change(function () {
            var number = $(this).attr("name").match(/\d+/g)[0];

            if (...condition...) {
                $('input[name="Options[' + i + '].Completed"]').filter('[value=False]').prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Also, there is no need to attach event on radio button in `for` loop individually.

You can use event delegation in jQuery.

```
$(document / parentSelector).on('change', 'input[name="Options[' + i + '].Completed"]', function () {
    // Event handling code here    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="radio" name="check" value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" name="check" value="2"/>
    <input type="radio" name="check" value="3"/>


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name=check]")
        .change(function(e){
            if($(e.target).val()=="2"){
                $(e.target).prop( "checked", false );
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aL86u746/

Comment: Em... as I can see, example are not working. + Actually no difference comparing to what I tried to do.

Comment: click action are not triggeren in my case.

Comment: Have you add jQuery library